# Apply the bitdojo_window package

Tags: flutter

I want to apply the bitdojo_window package to my program. Here, in the tutorial video provided by the publisher, I found that he and I had a different project directory. Where is my Windows directory? The web directory doesn't seem to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have windows enabled as platform. To do this you should follow the [official guide](https://flutter.dev/desktop) on the flutter website.

### But here a quick summary:

#### Install Visual Studio:

> Visual Studio 2019 (not to be confused with Visual Studio Code). For
> Win32 **you need the “Desktop development with C++” workload installed,
> including all of its default components**. For UWP you need the
> “Universal Windows Platform development” workload installed, with the
> optional UWP C++ tools.

#### run command in the terminal:

`flutter config --enable-windows-desktop`

now if you create a project it will automatically create this folder.

#### create Windows folder for existing project:

In case you want to get windows as platform in an existing project just run:

`flutter create .`

in the root directory of your project.